# PDF viewed can't open file - but only on tablet

Tags: android, pdf

I have an app that among other things fires up a pdf reader to allow the user to view a document selected by the app. It works on my phone but not Samsung tablet. The intent seems to work fine and the selection of reader apps comes up but when the reader is selected, a short time later the error message” Can’t open file “ is shown.
The same app can also fire up browser and text applications to show other files and this works fine on the tablet. So my file references are all OK. External storage for WRITE in the manifest is set OK.
When I select the document on the tablet (not thru my app) it opens OK. I have selected the pdf part of the main app and extracted it into a simple pdf reading only app and still the same problem.
It seems to be specific to the tablet – can anybody help me?

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File file1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Documents/A.pdf");
Uri ur=Uri.fromFile(file1);
i.setType("application/pdf");
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(i) ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all for help.  Actually I was just confused by the mime types. Read up on this and all is well.  App working perfectly along the lines posted by Ironman

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this code

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File file1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Documents/A.pdf");
Uri ur=Uri.fromFile(file1);
i.setType("application/pdf");
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(i) ;
```

Use this way

```
File pdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"namePdfFile.pdf");//File path
            if (pdfFile.exists()) //Checking for the file is exist or not
            {
                Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile);
                Intent objIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                objIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                objIntent.setFlags(Intent. FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(objIntent);//Staring the pdf viewer
            } else {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "The file not exists! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
```

### To Read PDF in Browser Use below code :

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
String pdf = "http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf";
webview.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I just did what you said and also put a Toast for file exists and the file exists.  When I select the viewer it still sayd "can't open file"

Comment: @Kalininskaya you want to read `PDF` in Browser or Inside the Application.

Comment: @Ironman - I was trying to do it in Browser essentially because it should be easier for me - inside the app would involve a lot of code and learning for me. I presume that by "browser" you mean for example an Adobe Reader?

Comment: @Kalininskaya I have put browser code see my update answer.

Comment: @Ironman  Sorry I gave wrong answer.  I was trying to read PDF in an app such as Adobe Reader not in a browser.  Thank you for the code but I was hoping for some help in finding the PDF file with the reader